# Website does not show default page

Tags: iis, web, publish, endpoint

I got an ASP.NET web application and as usual I published it, but it is not working. The error is:

> Endpoint not found. Please see the service help page for constructing valid requests to the service.

A `default.aspx` file is working fine, but when I publish the website it is not working. Note that there are `.svc` files in the root directory, maybe the issue is related to those.

Answer (score 0):

it is solved,

The reason is, I forgot code in Global.asax file , after I delete the following code it works fine,

Thanks!

```
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(DataManager)));
    }
```